# Changing root's passwords using setuid

Tags: password, root, setuid

Is is possible to change root's password using setuid?

What I tried is writing a simple program which calls `system("passwd root")` owned by root and its setuid bit is set but it didn't work.
The output is: `You may not view or modify password information for root.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your program, you probably overlooked making the real and effective uid set to the same value.  Gids also should match root's gid. Something like this:

```
setuid(geteuid());
setgid(getegid());
```

See for example [**`sue`**](http://invisible-island.net/misc_tools/index.html#item:sue) (a simple setuid/setgid wrapper).

Comment: Might he also need to set `USER` environment variable?

Comment: He  might - and `LOGNAME` - but the lack of proper permissions is the most likely problem.

Comment: OK, after some testing, I found only setuid(geteuid()) is need. Interestingly enough, running the program via ltrace or strace prevented seteuid from happening, so those traces were bogus.

Answer (score 0):

Thomas Dickey is absolutely right. However, don't do this. Use `sudo` instead.

Create `/etc/sudoers.d/change_root_pass`

```
YOURUSERNAME ALL = (ALL) passwd root
```

(Change YOURUSERNAME).